# Assigning values to each instance of Card in a deck of cards

Tags: ios, swift, struct, properties

I have a struct called Card and I've created a function that's supposed to create a deck of cards. I've found several threads on SO about creating decks of cards but they're either in Objective-C or assigning ranks and suits using enums which I'm not trying to do.

I have this array of strings:

```
let fibonacciSeries = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8", "13", "21", "34", "55", "89", "144", "∞"]
```

and I want my createDeck function to create a deck of cards using those values:

```
struct Card {

var name = String()

func createDeck(series: [String]) -> [Card] {
    var deck = [Card]()
    for value in series {
        deck.append(Card(name: value))
        print("The card name is \(self.name)")
        }
        return deck
    }
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
let myDeck = Card().createDeck(fibonacciSeries)
```

the name property is empty (or blank) for each card, which I can see with my print() call.

I tried changing my name property like this:

```
var name = ""
```

But they're still blank.

I researched some more and learned I can create a property without giving it a default value if I give it a value in an initializer so I added this:

```
init(name: String) {
  self.name = name
}
```

Still no joy because Xcode reminds me I need to pass a value for name in the Card() call and when I do that, all the cards are named the value I pass in.

Ultimately, I want to put these card into a UICollectionView and see these values but I seem to be caught in a circle with this name property and I can't get out.

I have looks at several threads here and none of the ones I could find provided an answer.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `name` property shouldn't actually be blank, your print statement is just wrong.  You're printing the name of the `Card` instance you're calling the method on, not the ones you are creating in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new `Card` instances and adding them to the array, but you aren't printing the `name` of the new `Card`, you are printing the `name` of `self`, which is the empty string you initialised it with.

If you printed the values of the cards in the array returned by `createDeck` then you would see the correct values.

The simple fix for your code, however, is to use a variable for the new card so that you can print it.

```
func createDeck(series: [String]) -> [Card] {
    var deck = [Card]()
    for value in series {
        let newCard=Card(name: value)
        deck.append(newCard)
        print("The card name is \(newCard.name)")
    }
    return deck
}
```

This is a slightly tortured use of a struct, however.  Since you want to have the `createDeck` function and structs can't have class functions, you end up having to create an instance of `Card` just so you can call `createDeck`.  You should either create a Card Class, or perhaps better in terms of object-oriented design, create a Deck struct.

```
struct Deck {
    var cards:[Card]

    init(_ series:[String]) {
            self.cards = [Card]()
            for value in series {
                let newCard=Card(name: value)
                self.cards.append(newCard)
                print("The card name is \(newCard.name)")
            }
    }
}


let myDeck = Deck(fibonacciSeries)

print(myDeck)
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I created the function in the Card struct because that's the way the Apple Swift Programming Guide examples kind of suggest.That didn't feel quite right so I'm glad you made this suggestion. A separate Deck struct makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems, the largest of which is that your `createDeck` function isn't declared static, so you can only invoke it in reference to an existing card.  When you call your print function, as paul points out, you're invoking it on the dummy instance you created so that you had a Card to use.  Making createDeck static solves that as it now no longer needs a card to operate on:

```
struct Card {
    var name = String()

    static func createDeck(series: [String]) -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()
        for value in series {
            deck.append(Card(name: value))
            print("The card name is \(self.name)")
        }
        return deck
    }
}

let fibonacciSeries = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8", "13", "21", "34", "55", "89", "144", "∞"]

let deck = Card.createDeck(fibonacciSeries)

print(deck[0].name)
```

And, fwiw, you can simplify `createDeck` as:

```
static func createDeck(series: [String]) -> [Card] {
    return series.map { Card(name: $0) }
}
```